# Problems accessing two different types of array

Tags: php, arrays

As a relative newbie to PHP I'm having trouble accessing the various elements in an array. I have to access two different types of array. The first example works fine although the second throws an error.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

PS. I come from a JavaScript, VBScript background so understand the concept of an array. Cheers!

The following code sample works

```
// Below is a dump of $dataArray
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[13]
       public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=15)
          'campaignID' => string '215999956' (length=9)

// Below writes out $dataArray
      foreach($dataArray as $val) {
           print $val['campaignID'];
          }
```

The following code sample doesn't work

```
// Below is a dump of $dataArray
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(AdGroup)[73]
      public 'campaignId' => string '112520126' (length=9)

// Below writes out $dataArray
      foreach($dataArray as $val) {
           print $val['campaignID'];
          }
```

Answer (score 3):

The first is an array and the second is an object. To access campaignID in the second version you will want to

```
print $val->campaignID
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second example you are iterating over an array with objects, so you must access your property with the arrow notation instead of trying to access it like an array:

```
foreach($dataArray as $val) {
    print $val->campaignID;
}
```